# Combine vba filters

Tags: excel, vba, filter

`Range("A2:K2000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("111", "222", "333"),Operator:=xlFilterValues`

This filters by 111, 222 or 333 and it works

`rework = "-R"`
`Range("A2:K2000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*" & rework`

This also works by filtering strings that end with -R, but how do I combine them? I need both first filter OR second filter.

I have tried
`Range("A2:K2000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("111", "222", "333", "*-R"),Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Doesnt work

I also tried

`Range("A2:K2000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("111", "222", "333"),Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*" & rework`

also not working

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could `Union` the result of the two filters

```
Sub Filtersss()

    Dim filteredRng As Range
    
        With Range("A2:K2000")
        
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("111", "222", "333"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        
            Set filteredRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            
            .AutoFilter
            Dim rework As String
                rework = "-R"
                .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="=*" & rework
                
            Set filteredRng = Union(filteredRng, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        
            .AutoFilter
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            filteredRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            
        End With
        
End Sub
```